# How to remove status bar while the 1st image launches

Tags: iphone, ios, launching-application

I want to know how remove the status bar when the first image is launching when I start the application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to check the corresponding box in Xcode > Summary > Status Bar.

[image]